# When will fees be finalized on the Alonzo testnet to reflect mainnet experience? Will it be on Sep 1?

Tags: testnet, fee

I noticed the fees being shown to the Alonzo testnet users haven't been representative.  It was mentioned on Aug Cardano 360 it is being finalized.  Will it be implemented right out of the gate on 1 September with the public testnet release?

Answer (score 1):

It is not confirmed yet, but that is the plan.